# Linux mint remove shortcut

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I want to remove shortcut from the upper panel in Linux. But right click gives me only "launch" and "properties" options..
How can i remove this shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check hidden files in your home folder.

Find

```
 ~/.config/gnome-panel/launchers
```

just delete any shortcut launcher that you want to.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on the shortcut. You will get a "Remove from panel" option.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking nowadays, the files are located here:

```
~/.gnome/apps

/home/{username}/.gnome/apps
```